# Crystal Report's report loading forever

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I've some Crystal reports in a VS2010 application. They all work fine, but sometimes (happened at least twice), they will stay on the hourglass without ever loading. If I launch another instance of the application and generate the report (while the other instance still loads), it works fine. If the non-working instance generates another report, it works fine. If the form is closed and reopened, it works fine.

So what may go wrong? There should be a timeout if there's an issue accessing the datasource.

Is this a bug or a known issue? I haven't found any info on that.

Is there a way to catch this "error" so the user doesn't waste his time for half an hour and then call me?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To catch problems like this you may need to add logging code to your app.
Make sure the Log function includes a time stamp, Pseudo code:

```
Log("pre-DB connect)
...DB connection
Log("post-DB connect)

Log("pre-Load Report...")
...load the report
Log("post-Load Report")
```

Once you narrow it down to a section of code, you can add more logging code to that section until hopefully, you zero in on the line that is hanging.

Comment: Well the line is crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = PayReport1;  So it really is in CR's loading and not in my code.